# Tomcat 6 gets dumb/idle

Tags: spring, tomcat, webserver

I am working on Spring REST web application with Hibernate that uses SQL server 2008 at back-end. I am using Tomcat 6 as a web server on 64-bit windows machine.

My application works good with this technology stack. But sometimes the tomcat server get dumb/idle suddenly. After getting dumb, the tomcat server doesn't process any request.

The tomcat server remains idle/dumb untill i press Ctrl+C from my keyboard to close it.But this action doesn't close tomcat server. In spite of this,  the tomcat get active again and process all the awaited request(that was in queue, at the time when the server was in idle state).

I have tried to increase the HEAP memory size for tomcat upto 1024 bytes. But it doesn't work for me. Please help me to solve this problem. Here is the the complete technology stack that i am using in my application.

OS - Windows server 2008
RAM-2 gb
Processor - Quad Core(2.45 Ghz) 64-bit
JAVA - JDK 1.6.0_30 (64 bit)
Tomcat Version - apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x64

Thanks in advance.
Arun Kumar

Comment: At the point of idle is there anything particular in the log (catalina.out etc)

Comment: @Shaun Hare - No. there is nothing happens at the idle time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing, it sounds like the Windows server is entering sleep mode. Can you verify ? Does any other service on the server respond during that period ?

Comment: No. During idle time, no service respond on server. But when server got re-activate it process all the pending services that were requested earlier.

Comment: If all services on the server (not only tomcat) stop responding, then its not a tomcat issue but a server issue. You can google for "window turn off sleep mode" for turning it off.

Comment: I mean the all the services contained in tomcat server stop responding,during tomcat idle time. But other tasks on windows continues.